# How do I use checkbox from icheck plugin?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-native

My code is :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card } from './Card';
import { Checkbox } from 'react-icheck';

class User extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <Checkbox
          checkboxClass="icheckbox_square-blue"
          increaseArea="20%"
          label="Do you want to receive notification ?"
        />
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

Error : Expected a component class, got[object Object].
I don't know why I am getting errors for Checkbox Component.

version :

```
"icheck": "^1.0.2",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-icheck": "^0.3.8",
"react-native": "0.47.1",
```

Can anyone say where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use `react-icheck` with `react-native`. `react-icheck` uses DOM elements.

Comment: thanks for your comment @AndrewLi

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone say where I am doing wrong ?

You are trying to use DOM based Components inside a `react-native` application.

*I don't think, that I should explain the difference*